# How to specifiy the query string in an RSpec test of a Rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I have an action called `yearly_csv`. In this action I perform two operations like demand and supply.

```
def yearly_csv
   if demand == 'true'
       demand_csv
   else
       supply_csv
   end
end
```

I have two radio buttons in my view to select one of the operations. Now I want to test each operation individually in RSpec. For example, one spec for supply and another spec for demand.
My question is how to pass the radio button value to the `yearly_csv` action (get)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In an RSpec controller spec, specify query parameters as a hash argument to `get`:

```
describe YourController
  describe '#yearly_csv'
    # set up
    get :yearly_csv, demand: 'true'
    # assert results
  end
end
```

Comment: Well there you go. See above.

Answer (score 29):

In newer versions for RSpec, you must declare query string params using the `params` key:

```
get :yearly_csv, params: { demand: 'true' }
```

Comment: it would be nice to find from which version it changed to be a param